# Selecting an IoC container for asp.net webapi

Tags: ioc-container

I am looking for an ioc container to use for asp.net webapi. Couple of the key feature we are looking for are as follow

- Custom lifetimes
- Built-in support for web request lifetime
- Good integration with web api in terms of manage the dependency registration.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Seemann knows his DI/Ioc and has an article on implementing it for Wep Api with Castle Windsor [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/). I don't know about custom lifetimes but it definitely solves the second and third requirements.

Castle is not as lightweight as say [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration) but it's been around for years and is tried and tested: I am using Castle for my Web Api and Mvc projects without issue so far.

Both should do the job though.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/). The reason why I use Unity is that it is build by Microsoft and with that you can expect that it is nearly up-to-date. Also I had prior experience with it and it has good support for ASP.NET Web API, but the final choice for or against a container is up to you. It really dependent on personal flavor.

There's a small part in the ASP.NET tutorials which talks about [using Unity with Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver).

Comment: Yeah, another reason for Unity might be continuity - for example, if you have a WPF app in the same solution that uses Prism/Unity and as a team you want to be consistent with your DI approach as well as benefiting from sharing any extensions you end up writing.

Comment: Thanks @santos! This is one of the best things about Unity. You can use it in other projects as well.